# Cyclic dependency in test cases

Tags: dependencies, elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I have three apps in umbrella project setup

1. **Datalayer**
2. **ApiLayer**
3. **OtherLayer** Some Other layer(but mandatory)

Now I have dependencies defined like this in mix file
App **ApiLayer** has

```
{:OtherLayer, in_umbrella: true},
{:Datalayer, in_umbrella: true}
```

App **Datalayer** has no dependency of the umbrella apps
App **OtherLayer** has

```
{:Datalayer, in_umbrella: true}
```

But test cases which are being called from app **ApiLayer**  needs to call context defined in **Datalayer** and context of **Datalayer** in turn needs to access some functionalities to **OtherLayer** but can't. because if I add its dependency in **Datalayer**. This will be cyclic dependency case. I need to pass my test cases. is there some way to load some chunk of the code without creating cyclic dependency?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have tried some solutions like dynamically requiring that module but didn't work and tried ensure_all_started option in test_helper but got
{:error, {:m, {:invalid_restart_type, :data_layer}}}

Comment: If they really are so integrated, they should probably not be separate applications. One solution would probably be to handle that kind of communication by passing the module to the function.
For example if you have a method in your ApiLayer that calls DataLayer, but DataLayer also needs values from OtherLayer, you could design the function in DataLayer to accept the module as an argument and pass it in ApiLayer. `def my_func(x), do: DataLayer.Module.func(x, OtherLayer.DependencyModule)`

Answer (score 0):

If `OtherLayer` is always included with an application that already has `Datalayer` as a dependancy, then you can remove the `Datalayer` dependancy from `OtherLayer`, as the application will be included in your release anyway. If you need to build `OtherLayer` as a stand-alone application then create an `OtherLayerWrapper` application that has `Datalayer` and `OtherLayer` as dependancies.